# Como dejar de ignorar un archivo específico con git

Tags: git, gitignore

Tengo un proyecto en Git que contiene una gran cantidad de archivos `json` resultados de la ejecución que no deseo controlar. Así que agrego esta línea a mi archivo `.gitignore`:

```
tramites.csv
*.json
ptime.exe
```

Ahora bien, esto tiene como efecto secundario que se ignora el archivo **`packages.json`** y el proyecto usa Node, por lo que dicho archivo es imprescindible.

#### ¿Cómo puedo controlar `packages.json` y al mismo tiempo ignorar al resto de archivos `json`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para seguir un archivo cuando se deben ignorar los del mismo tipo usamos un modificador de negación sobre el mismo, por ejemplo:

```
# Ignorar ficheros JSON
*.json

#Seguir un fichero JSON concreto
!packages.json
```

Answer (score 5):

Normalmente deberías poder controlar packages.json si lo agregas con la negación `!` después de *.json:

```
*.json
!packages.json
```